# helm : error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line xx: did not find expected key

Tags: arrays, list, go, kubernetes-helm, jsondecoder

I have a json encoded string in my values.yaml file ->

**values.yaml**

```
network:
  cidrs : "[\"123.123.123.123/32\",\"123.124.125.125/32\"]"
```

Now , I want to use this value as a list of string in my network policy egress ipblock. But I'm not able to convert it to list.

Currently, I'm following this to achieve the requirement , but it fails -

> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line xx : did not find expected key

**netpol.yaml**

```
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: log-forwarder
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  {{- $json := .Values.network.cidrs | fromJson -}}
  {{- range $json }}
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: {{- . }}
  {{- end }}
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
```

Any idea , how to convert the encoded string to list of string and use it in my network policy ?

Comment: Would the logic be simpler if `.Values.network.cidrs` was a list, rather than a JSON-encoded string?  If you run `helm template --debug` over the chart, is it obvious which part has incorrect YAML syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mustFromJson` instead of `fromJson`, had the same problem recently and that fixed it, gonna have a look in the docs to see if I find out why.

edit: for some reason `fromJson` cant handle top level lists, but `mustFromJson` can, looks like a bug as the only difference listed in the docs is that `mustFromJson` returns an error in case the JSON is invalid.

[source](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/defaults.html#:%7E:text=fromJson%2C-,mustFromJson,-fromJson%20decodes%20a)